# My jquery works local but when it's uploaded to my website it only works partly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

When I open my page on localhost it works fine. But when I upload it to my website, only a part executes.

This is my jquery. There also are no errors in the console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var folder = "/img/krokus2016/";
$.ajax({
    url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(folder);

            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
                    $(".lijst").append("<li><img src='"+val+"'></li>");
                } 
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your `/img/krokus2016/` folder exists in your site root. Do you have Directory Browsing permission? Or do you have index.html (or whatever returned by default) with links to your images?
Check response from the server. I bet it is 403.

Comment: I fixed, it indeed was the Directory Browsing permission

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a relative route in `var folder = "/img/krokus2016/";` instead of an absolute one?

For example `var folder = "img/krokus2016/";` without the `/`.

Comment: Yes, but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way and tell us back what error it produces in the console:

```
var folder = "/img/krokus2016/"
    $.ajax({
        url: folder
    }).done(function(response) { 
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log('Error = '+thrownError+' , Error Status = '+xhr.status+' , ajaxOptions = '+ajaxOptions);
    });
```

Comment: That means that the "/img/krokus2016/" is not the correct path if it returns a 404 error. Look in your network console and see what 404 error you are getting. se if has 404.something in there. My guess is the the "img" folder is not in the root on your website.

Comment: Not really, what am I meant to do? It says that "/img/krokus2016/" is the initiator of the 404. Is that because the path might be wrong?

Comment: Look at the file structure on your web server and make sure your "img" folder is sitting in the web sites root folder.

Comment: Ok, so I did some more research and I found that if I add "Options +Indexes" to my .htacces file it will show the canvas of the pictures. But still not the pictures